# C++ Overloading Of Functions? Area of Circle

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to get area of circle using my program. But area is not coming in decimals.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


float AreaOfCircle(float r);
int AreaOfCircle(int r);

int main()
{int rad;
    cout<<"Enter the Radius of Crircle: ";
    cin>>rad;
    cout<<"The Are of the Cirlcle: "<<AreaOfCircle(rad);

}
float AreaOfCircle(float r)
{
    int area=0;
    area=2*3.1456*r*r;
    return area;
}

int AreaOfCircle(int r)
{
    int area=0;
    area=2*3.1456*r*r;
    return area;
}
```

But I need answer to some decimal point.

Comment: By the way, the area of a circle with radius `r` is: `pi * r * r`.

Comment: I don't see why you need two functions. Isn't it just reduplication of code? cout << (int)AreaOfCircle(rad) << '\n'; if you want to output the integer part of the result, no matter what rad is.

Comment: We have two ways to do this, either to use Type Casting or Overloading of Method or Function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not calling the `float` version of the method.

Either declare your variable as `float`

```
float rad;
```

or cast it to `float` before you call the method.

```
AreaOfCircle((float)rad);
```

You also need to use `float` instead of `int` inside the overloaded method:

```
float AreaOfCircle(float r)
{
    float area=0;   // <--- float here
    area=2*3.1456*r*r;
    return area;
}
```

Also:

```
area = pi * r * r
length = 2 * pi * r
pi ~= 3.1415
```

Comment: In addition, the `float`-version must be changed internally, too. It currently uses `int` to store the result of the calculation temporarily.

Comment: `2 * pi * r` is called circumference of a circle.

Comment: Thanks for all your input! I messed my program

Comment: @yasouser it's actually `Length of circumference`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to answer by @Luchian, you need to change the returned value to a `float`:

```
float AreaOfCircle(float r)
{
    int area=0;        // <<----- float area = 0;
    area=2*3.1456*r*r;
    return area;
}
```

change to:

```
float AreaOfCircle(float r)
{
    float area=0;
    area=2*3.1456*r*r;
    return area;
}
```

or just:

```
float AreaOfCircle(float r) { return 2*3.1456*r*r; }
```

Comment: @jogojapan, that is what I am stating here?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will call the overload it feels is the best match to the types of parameters it is passed. Because you passed an int, it assumed you wanted the int version.

By casting to a float as Luchian suggested (or using a float in the first place) you are telling the compiler that you intend the parameter to be a float type - thus, it picks the float version.

Comment: Thanks for giving me this suggestion.